# Making a swift app compatible with different operating systems

Tags: ios, swift3

I want to make an app using swift that will accept credit card payments for physical goods.  I want the app to be compatible with ios as well as android and others.  Should I make a web app instead of going through app store and is there a secure way to do this (with respect to credit card processing)?  Are there any straight forward tutorials? Please help me I'm stuck! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to port a Swift/Objective-C application to Java or vice versa without some additional work.

A hybrid application is written with HTML, CSS, and JavaScript but acts like a native application. [Apache Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/) allows you to write one code base and then package the application for iOS, Android, and several other operating systems.

As for credit card processing, there are Cordova plug-ins like [this one for PayPal](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Cordova-Plugin).

If you want the widest range of options and greatest security when it comes to processing payments, a responsive web application would be a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a cross platform language and development environment that supports the development of Android and iOS store apps and doesn't use Javascript or other web development tools, you can use Xamarin from Microsoft which supports C# (and F#). C# is derived from Java but provides some language features that Swift also supports but Java does not such as structs, properties, tuples and extension methods.